# Error on Validation for Address Contact and dropdown list

Tags: javascript, validation

I have been trying to validate:

Contact = > Trying to create minimum and maximum number ( Right now the whole code seems like it's not working at all.
Dropdown list = > Doesn't even work.

HTML Codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="validation.js"></script>
    
</head>
    
    
<body onload="document.registration.fname.focus();">
    
    
    <div class="container">
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="form-area">
        <form name='registration' onSubmit="return formValidation(event);" method="GET" action="Thank_You.html">
        <br style="clear: both">
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px;">Registration Form</h3>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="fname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control required" id="fname" placeholder=" ">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control required" id="lname" placeholder="Optional ">
            </div>
            
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                    <p>
                        <input type="radio" name="msex"  value="male"> Male
                        <input type="radio" name="fsex"  value="female"> Female
                    </p>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="address">Residential Address</label>
                <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control required" id="address" placeholder=" ">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="contact">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="contact" class="form-control required" id="contact" placeholder=" ">
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="course">Course Selection</label>
                    <select name="courseSelection" class="form-control required" id="courseSelection">
                        <option value="select">Select a Course</option>
                        <option value="java">Programming in Java</option>
                        <option value="net">Programming in .Net</option>
                        <option value="msoffice">Microsoft Office</option>
                        <option value="html">HTML</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
            
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit Form</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function formValidation()
{
    var ufname = document.registration.fname;
    var umsex = document.registration.msex;
    var ufsex = document.registration.fsex;
    var uadd = document.registration.address;
    var contact = document.registration.contact;
    var selection = document.registration.courseSelection;

    {
        if (allLetter(ufname, 4, 20))
    {
        if (validsex(umsex, ufsex))
    {
        if (validaddress(uadd))
    {
        if (Validucontact(contact, 9, 11))
    {
        if (VaildSelect(selection ))
    {
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
        return false;
}

function allLetter(fname, minLen, maxLen) 
{
    var NameLength = fname.value.length;
    if (NameLength == 0 || NameLength > maxLen || NameLength < minLen) { // || - Or operator
        alert("First Name should not be empty / length must be between " + minLen + " to " + maxLen);
        fname.focus();
        return false;
    } else if (!isAlpha(fname)) {        //! - Not operator
        alert("Enter alphabets only");
        fname.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function isAlpha(input) 
{
    var characters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/; // Regular Expression [ ] - Options , A-Z - A,B, C ... Z, ^ - Any 
    if (input.value.match(characters)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function validsex(umsex,ufsex)
{
    x=0;

    if(umsex.checked) 
    {
        x++;
    } 
    if(ufsex.checked)
    {
        x++; 
    }
    if(x==0)
    {
        alert('Select Male/Female');
        umsex.focus();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        
        return true;}
}

function validaddress(uadd) {
    
        if (uadd.value.length == 0) {
             alert("Address must be filled out");
             
        return false;
  }
}

function Validucontact() {
        //var contacts = document.registration.contact;
        var contactLength = contact.value.length;
        
        if (contactLength == 0 || contactLength < 9 || contactLength > 11) {
            alert("Contact should not be empty / length must be " + 9 + " to " + 11);
            contacts.focus();
            
        } 
            
        if (!isNumber(contacts)) {
            
            contacts.focus();
            return false;
        }
       
        return true;
    }

    function isNumber(input) {
        
        var characters = "/^[0-9{8}]+$/";
        if (input.value.match(characters)) {
            
            return true;

        }
            
         alert("Enter Numbers only");
        return false;
    }

  function VaildSelect(selection)
{
    if (selection.value == "select")
    {
        alert("Please select a course");
        document.getElementById("courseSelection").focus();
        return false;
    }
        return true;
}
```

I sincerely need some help on this as I really don't know what to do....
Address issue have been solve but the contact & dropdown list issue still there

Comment: Adding to one more thing... For first name when validate it don't allow spacing. Why is that? Example results should be : John Doe |   | Validate codes results : JohnDoe

Answer (score 0):

Element IDs are case sensitive. You have `document.getElementById("courseselection")` in order to get an element with the ID `courseSelection`. You need to make both of them the same.

Also, it seems you are trying to call a function `ValidSelect`. You have no such function, but you do have `ValidDropdwn`.

The main problem is in `validsex`. It will always stop validation because it comes before the validation of the address field, the contact field, and the dropdown field. If it passes, it will display "Form successfully submitted" and reload the page. This stops the entire thing and doesn't even check anything else.

Comment: i have re correct it but still it didn't prompt anything

Comment: See my answer, I updated it with a solution that should get you somewhere. You weren't even calling the other validation functions because it was stopping unconditionally at `validsex`.